# How to use FillChar to fill a 3D integer array (four bytes) in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi, fillchar

I know this works:

```
type _AAAB = array of array of array of byte;

procedure fillArray(var arr: _AAAB; const v: byte); overload;
var
  i, j, k: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(arr) do
  begin
    for j := 0 to High(arr[i]) do
    begin
      FillChar(arr[i][j][0], Length(arr[i][j]), v); // sizeof(byte)=1
    end;
  end;
end;
```

However, if the array is type of integer, 4 byte, the above will not work as expected.. What i want to do here is to speed up the following:

```
type _AAAI = array of array of array of integer;

procedure fillArray(var arr: _AAAI; const v: integer); overload;
var
  i, j, k: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(arr) do
  begin
    for j := 0 to High(arr[i]) do
    begin
      for k := 0 to High(arr[i][j]) do
      begin
        arr[i][j][k] := v;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

by replacing the inner loop... any advices? any faster method than FillChar? FillChar fills with byte, so it is not good here.

Comment: Do you want to fill, or reset the array?

Comment: Matheus Freitas fill array with a value.

Comment: I take it this question actually has nothing to do with 3-D arrays. You're just asking how to fill arrays with values larger than one byte. The extra dimensions of the array are irrelevant, are they not?

Comment: How do you know this is a performance bottleneck?

Comment: If you use High(arr) you should also (for consistency) use Low(arr). Don't assume that the lower bound is 0 - it could be something else (in cases of statically defined arrays, like ARRAY[3..7] OF INTEGER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [multibyte analogue to `FillChar`, such as `FillWord` or `FillDWord`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2113182/33732). You might have to write those functions yourself, if your environment doesn't already include them.